# Column chart with % and currency

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I'm trying to do a column chart in Excel. I have these values:

[image: table with values]

But I get something like this:

[image: histogram chart]

However, I'd like something like this:

[image: histogram chart]

How can I get that?

Comment: The chart in your screen cap doesn't seem to correspond to the table. Can you provide a chart and data that match?

Comment: You're going to confuse people with a column chart (it's not a histogram, by the way) that shows different quantities on different axes. It is very hard to help people recall that two bars are currencies on one axis and one of the bars is a percentage on the other axis. I suggest that when you move your percentage to the secondary axis, you also change its chart type to a line with markers. It will still confuse people, but not so badly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way of getting what you want.

1. Add three columns to your chart, format two as percentages and the other as currency:

[image]

2. Insert a chart (doesn't really matter what kind for now)
3. Right-click on it and choose "Select Data..." from the pop-up menu
4. Click on "Switch Row/Column so that the column headers (demand, export, etc...) are on the left hand side
5. Move the "filler" series up until they are just below the "demand" series

[image]

6. Click "OK", then right-click on the chart and select "Change Chart Type..." from the pop-up menu
7. Select Combo chart as the chart type
8. Select "Clustered Columns for all Series, and check "Secondary Axis for the first three.

[image]

9. Click "OK"
10. In the legend, select and delete the legend entries for the filler series

[image]

And you're done

[image]